# How to get the order of two vectors based on their relative angle without computing the angle?

Tags: javascript, vector, angle, vectormath

[I've illustrated what I'm looking for here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gfmf.png)

In case it is not clear from the image, here is what my problem is:

I have two vectors with the same origin. I want to be able to check if v1 is to the left of v2.
It's as if v1 was an axis and i wanted v2 to have a positive angle to it if that makes sense.

I've already tried using atan2(x, y) but I don't know how to make the value consistent when one vector is < 0 and the other is > 0 (when both vectors are facing down)

I've read about possibly doing a 2d cross product (which isn't technically a thing but its done by projecting the two vectors onto an axis) but I'm not sure how to implement it and I don't know if it's a working solution.

I am using Javascript for an html canvas game engine but that is unrelated to the question because I just need to know how to do the math in this case.

---

I hope that I am clear in what my problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: Towards your cross product part: `(v11, v12, 0) ⨯ (v21, v22, 0)`, check if the third component is positive or negative. See [wikipedia illustration](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Cross_product.gif).

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thank you! I implemented this and it's exactly what I needed!
It sounds logical that it would work now that I think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried atan2(y,x) rather than atan2(x,y)?

One probably also would want to address angles being a bit < Pi and > Pi with some logic. As in the question, "Is 359 degress > 0 or is it anti clockwise?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I realize that my problem comes from situations where one vector is nearing  -Pi and the other nearing +Pi.
I'll have to check if it works but @ASDFGerte gave an answer that makes it easier to just know the order of the two without knowing the angle, which is just what I need.

However, I'm still curious, why would doing atan2(y,x) give a better result than atan2(x,y)?